# Custom errors show up only locally, but not on remote server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I've created custom errors for my ASP.NET MVC application and for some reason they only show up on my local machine, but when I deploy my application on remote server the default IIS error pages show up (404 and 500) and I would like to understand why it is so. Here is my app configuration:

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    ...
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ServerError">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound" />
        </customErrors>
    ...
</system.web>
```

**Routes configuration**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Error - 404",
        "NotFound",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Error - 500",
        "ServerError",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "ServerError" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Error controller:**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```

Local machine IIS configuration and remote one look similar, but maybe I've missed something and I have to configure it properly as well.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        return View();
    }
}
```